# Calculate chance a Jackpot (slotmachine) falls

Tags: probability

This might be a simple question (or not) but since I'm no mathematician by a long shot, I'm asking here.

Suppose I have kept track of a slotmachine's winnings. And I know exactly when in the past few years the jackpot has been won and how high it was on each occasion. Can I give any value to the probability the jackpot will be hit today? Like in "there's a n% chance the Jackpot will be won today"?

Comment: If it's a fair game, the probability/chance will be the same on any given day. That's how random stuff works. However, the machine was built by humans so there is some pseudo-random logic in it which may result in different probabilities on different days. However, I expect the difference to be negligible.

Comment: @Vasya Slot machines are certainly not fair games: they are always favourable for the "house".  Depending on the programming, the probability of winning the jackpot might be constant for any particular play, but almost certainly the probability of a win on a day will depend on how many times the machine is played that day.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to figure out the internal workings of the slot machine by looking at how it behaves.

If the computer program (or other mechanism) inside the machine "decides" whether or not to display a jackpot without paying any attention to the past history of payouts then the most likely number of jackpots today is the fraction
$$
\frac{\text{number of jackpots you've seen}}
{\text{number of days you've been watching}} .
$$
If the machine is cleverer than that you're out of luck.

**Edit** in response to comment. You are really asking a very subtle question about probability.

If you **know** the probability of a jackpot on a day and the days are independent then indeed the fact that you haven't seen one in a while does not mean you are "due" for one soon, or that you are less likely to see one soon. That probability does not change from day to day,

But in the situation you ask about do not know that probability. You are trying to estimate it based on the information you have gathered. In that case when you haven't seen a jackpot for a long time you should conclude that the machine is programmed to make jackpots rare, so the probability of a jackpot today does really decrease the more days you go without seeing one. To get some intuition about this, suppose you watch me flip an **unfair** coin. The probability of heads is not $1/2$, but you do not know what it is. Then if you see $100$ tosses with just $20$ heads you would reasonably guess that heads will come up $20\%$ of the time.

Comment: Like I said, I'm no mathematician, but that feels a bit counter-intuitive. Because it means the longer the jackpot hasn't been won, the more the chance decreases (since the number of days I've been watching increases, but the number of jackpots I've seen remains the same).

Comment: @Zippy1970 Good question. See my edit.

Comment: In the case of the unfair coin, after you have examined the data and figured out that heads only comes up 20% of the time, then doesn't the chance that heads comes up increases with every subsequent toss of tails? I mean after heads has come up, the chance heads comes up again in the next toss is 1 in 5, right? If tails has come up five times in a row, is the chance still 1 in 5 heads comes up? Logically I would say yes, but like I said, that feels counter-intuitive.

Comment: If after you've seen $20$ heads in $100$ tosses you see $5$ heads in a row you update your estimate of the probability of heads to $25/105 \approx 24\%$ from $20\%$. At each moment all you have to go on is what you have seen so far. (This argument is due originally to Laplace.)

Comment: I understand that all you have to go on, is what you have seen so far. But back to the slot machine. Suppose I have recorded 10 jackpot hits. And the number of days between subsequent jackpots is 20, 35, 24, 21, 40, 28, 32, 22 and 31 days. So up to now, the number of days between jackpots has always been between 20 and 40 days. Doesn't that mean the chances of a new jackpot hit are lower on day one (after the previous jackpot hit) than day 20? My apologies if I ask stupid questions... ;)

Comment: It might mean that, if the slot machine is programmed to space out jackpots. My answer assumes the probability of a jackpot is the same every day and estimates the probability. You could write another model that adds random spacing to the calculation. Then you would have to estimate two parameters. So part of your intuition must be based on a guess about the underlying random mechanism. (These are not stupid questions, but they are more subtle than you might think.)